# What's the use of bpy.ops.ed.flush_edits()

Tags: python, scripting

There has a function in blender api:

```
bpy.ops.ed.flush_edits()
```

Here is the description of the document:   https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.ed.html
`Flush edit data from active editing modes`

So, what does it mean?

Comment: I can't seem to find any reference to `bpy.ops.ed` anywhere in the Python code in the github mirror.

Comment: @MartyFouts https://github.com/blender/blender/blob/master/source/blender/editors/util/ed_util.c#L237-L284 no idea what it's actually doing though :) also there are a few references to the operation there https://github.com/blender/blender/blob/master/source/blender/bmesh/intern/bmesh_mesh_convert.cc#L593-L606

Comment: @Gorgious interesting. Did you find the Python code that invokes it? I’ll try to figure it out when I am back on a keyboard.

Comment: @Gorgious I've gone over that code, including looking at [T84920](https://developer.blender.org/T84920) and I'm pretty sure you don't want to know what it's actually doing.

Comment: @MartyFouts hehe thanks for the archeology trip ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems, from looking at the [C source code](https://github.com/blender/blender/blob/master/source/blender/editors/util/ed_util.c#L250) that [Gorgious](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/86891/gorgious) discovered and some bug reports related to the source code such as [T84920](https://developer.blender.org/T84920) that this family of functions isn't really meant to be used from Python.  Certainly most of the functions don't have actual Python APIs.

Very roughly, edits are multiple step operations internally and the editors maintain state that they use during the multiple steps.  The flush operation transfers the internal state to the actual state of the edited object.

Without actually asking the developers on Chat, I don't think we'll get a better understanding than this.